# Accents problem on GTK application on Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

I have installed Kubuntu 15.04 which looks awesome. My French-Canadian Keyboard is well configured and I can type word with accents fine on KDE app like Kate. But if I'm on skype, firefox or other GTK application, accents are written before the lettre like this: ¸c, ¨e. Only letter "é" seems okay.

Anyone could help to solve this issue ?

Comment: I have the same problem as you do

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a latin-american spanish keyboard. In order to solve it, I created a file named ".xprofile" in my home directory. Then, I wrote the following line in it:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

I suppose fcitx is the default input method of KDE in Kubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: Worked after rebooting.

Comment: Great news,  I need to test it next time I install Kubuntu !